# Incremental totals in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a table as below:
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoZRv.png)

and I have a model as

```
class Hours(models.Model):
      name = model.Charfield(max_length =200)
      hours = DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places=2)

     def total_hours(self):
        queryset = Hours.objects.aggregate(total_hours=models.Sum('hours'))
        return queryset['total_hours']
```

now when I run the code I get all records have the to 37 instead of them having a running total.

where did I miss a step?

Comment: whenever you call total_hours its getting the sum of hours over all Hours objects. You'd need something like Hours.objects.filter(id__lte=self.id).aggregate(total_hours=models.Sum('hours')) for a running total

Comment: Hi @Henty thank you so much, please put this as an answer so I can accept it as a solution. its doing exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you call total_hours its getting the sum of hours over all Hours objects. You'd need something like:

```
Hours.objects.filter(id__lte=self.id).aggregate(total_hours=models.Sum('hours'))
```

for a running total